# How to add the table content by using Selenium WebDriver + Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

We are using tables to show our data. I am able to print the text of an particular row. But there is problem here. The text is in the below format
45 (46), 64 (67), 117 (133)

Now i want to add only 45, 64, 117 and print the sum value.

The HTML page is like this

```
   <td style="padding-right:5px;text-align:right;">45 (46)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="padding-right:5px;text-align:right;">64 (67)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="padding-right:5px;text-align:right;">117 (133)</td>
  </tr>
```

What i need to do ?...

Comment: You'll want to parse the returned string using regex or whatever string parsing methods the language you're using supports. You may want to share what language you are using if you want examples. If you search stackoverflow for "parse string" and you're language of choice you'll find more examples than you'll need.

Comment: I am using Java as a coding language.