# How to Iterate only last column data of each row, When the table decreases exponentially

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML table with tr and td.The values gets changed according to the Date selection given. I need to iterate each row, last column data and add them.  The value decreases by one for each row.
Please help me, How to get only last column data of each row. The image is attached below and it is highlighted.

[ClickHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIfDf.png)

```
HTML code
<div class="row">
<div id="installCohort" class="col-md-12">
<div class="cornelius-container">
<table class="cornelius-table">
<tr>
<th class="cornelius-time">Time</th>
<th class="cornelius-people">Installs</th>
<th class="cornelius-people">1</th>
<th class="cornelius-people">2</th>
<th class="cornelius-people">3</th>
<th class="cornelius-people">4</th>
<th class="cornelius-people">5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cornelius-label">October 2016</td>
<td class="cornelius-people">3</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-extra-hot" title="3">3</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-medium-high" title="1">1</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-low">0</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-low">0</td>
**<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-low">0</td>**
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cornelius-label">November 2016</td>
<td class="cornelius-people">16056</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-hot" title="10790">10790</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-high" title="7861">7861</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-high" title="7186">7186</td>
**<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-high" title="7186">7186</td>**
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cornelius-label">December 2016</td>
<td class="cornelius-people">85254</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-high" title="38098">38098</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-medium-high" title="33857">33857</td>
**<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-medium-high" title="33790">33790</td>**
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cornelius-label">January 2017</td>
<td class="cornelius-people">24814</td>
<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-high" title="14883">14883</td>
**<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-high" title="14839">14839</td>**
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cornelius-label">February 2017</td>
<td class="cornelius-people">227</td>
**<td class="cornelius-absolute cornelius-extra-hot" title="226">226</td>**
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cornelius-label">March 2017</td>
**<td class="cornelius-people">0</td>**
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
<td class="cornelius-empty">-</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you see the above image, The values are decreasing exponencially and even the element tags are changing as cornelius-low, cornelius-high, cornelius-medium and so on.

I tried the below spinets of codes in keeping in loops. As the element tags are changing, unable to  fetch only 0, 7186, 33790, 14839, 226

Comment: Add the `html` snippet for the same not image

Comment: Didn't you post a similar question here only a little while ago? In any case, please share your code, so that someone can help you with it. Otherwise, it's basically writing a solution from scratch.

Comment: @barakmanos Are you talking about [**this one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347991/how-to-add-the-table-content-by-using-selenium-webdriver-java)?

Comment: @Mistalis: No, I'm pretty sure I saw a similar question (with fewer details) posted a very little while ago.

Comment: Yeah, i am the one. Who posted previously. But that of another question completely. I solved it and able to fetch the content in brackets. This is different question

Comment: Hello Hi, I have kept complete HTML spinet code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code to get last `td` of each `tr`:

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findelements(By.xpath('//table[@class="cornelius-table"]//tr[not(th)]'));
Iterator<WebElement> iter = rows.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    WebElement tr = iter.next();
    td = tr.findelement(By.xpath('./td[not(@class="cornelius-empty")][last()]'));
    System.out.println(td.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code. Getting === FAILED: demoAppVerification
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//td[last()]"}  //////

.//td[last()] = Whats the use of this element. Does it fetch the last column of a row.

Comment: I guess it's because `<tbody>` element generated automatically, try to use `'//table[@class="cornelius-table"]//tr'` instead of `'//table[@class="cornelius-table"]/tr'`. `td[last()]` should match the very last element `td` of each `tr`

Comment: I tried it, But still facing an issue. Getting- NoSuchElementException for this locator ..   .//td[last()]

Comment: Try `System.out.println(rows.size()); `. Does it returns number greater than `0`?

Comment: Hello Hi, I have kept complete HTML spinet code.  And i am getting a row count of 6. When i inspect by Fire-path and the x path is selecting only the last column completely. Its not selecting each row, last column value.

Comment: Answer updated with new `XPath` expressions. Now it should work. Don't forget to mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Andersson. Can you explain, 
1- How did you find 'not' will solve the issue. 
2- But the xpath is selecting all the last column values of the page. " //td[not(@class="cornelius-empty")][last()] "
Thanks for the answer Man.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain... All last `td`s, except first, returns text as `"-"`, so we cannot use just `[last()]` "marker", but we need last **non-empty** `td`- `td`, that **doesn't contain** class `"cornelius-empty"`

Answer (score 0):

**@Andersson** code should work for you. If not, then as per his suggestion there might be `tbody` popping up while the page is loaded. So, you can just replace his code to the one below (I have also added the `WebElement` Interface reference that was missing for `td`):

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='cornelius-table']//tr"));
Iterator<WebElement> iter = rows.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    WebElement tr = iter.next();
    WebElement td = tr.findElement(By.xpath("./td[not(@class='cornelius-empty') and last()]"));
    System.out.println(td.getText());
    }
}
```

If the above still doesn't work, you can try the below one, which is just the more optimized version using xpath:

```
List<WebElement> tabledata = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='cornelius-table']//tr/td[not(@class='cornelius-empty') and last()]"));
for(WebElement td: tabledata)
 System.out.println(td.getText());
```

The above code will find all the last `td` element in each rows of table with `class` as `cornelius-table` and put it in a list `tabledata`. Then using for-each loop, iterate through the list `tabledata`, fetch and print the innerText.

**EDIT** I have modified the above code snippets as per the HTML snippet provided by OP.

Comment: Getting only the last column data.  IF you see the above image. 9665 column is getting printed in the console. But it should decrease exponentially.

Comment: @Ram, thanks for adding the HTML snippet. Please find the updated code snippet above. Now the xpath will locate the `tabledata` which comes at the last and doesn't contain the class `cornelius-empty` which apparently was coming at the end and had no data in it.